# Can a connected manifold with nonempty boundary be embedded into a connected manifold without boundary and with the same dimension?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let M be a connected m-dimension manifold with nonempty boundary.
My question is whether there exists **a connected m-dimension manifold N without boundary**  and countinuous map $ f: M\to N $ such that $ f $ is an embedding? Moreover, is every manifold with boundary can be viewed as a regular domain of a manifold without boundary?

Comment: This is just a vague intuition, but shouldn't you be able to do this constructively by appending a little "open blob" that connects to the boundary?  Sort of along the lines of a point-at-infinity compactification, though you'd need more than just a single point.

Comment: You should manage to glue $M$ with a mirror image copy $M'$ of itself with the required charts for points of the (former) boundary constructed in the obvious manner

Comment: @user3716267 The problem is how do you deal with the overlaps between those "open blob" you have mentioned? I do have considered embedding each neighborhood of the boundary point into an open set in Euclidean space, but I failed to construct it globally for the overlaps may not agree with each other.

Comment: It might help to look up collar neighborhoods.

Comment: The construction Hagen von Eitzen describes is calle the [double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_(manifold)) of a manifold with nonempty boundary. It isn't the only choice for such a embedding, but it is a pretty standard choice.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks for hints! It seems like a feasible way to construct an example. I will put the detailed prosess below after I figure it out :)

Comment: @Kajelad Thanks for hint. It seems like an pretty good example.